# simple ruby unless method mistake

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I am very new to ruby. This might sound very naive to you but I can't understand what is happening here

```rb
matched_criteria = match_criteria(c1, c2)
puts "answer is #{matched_criteria}"

def match_criteria(crit_val1, crit_val2)
  if crit_val1.present?
    puts "present"
  else
    puts "absent"
  end

  return true unless crit_val1.present? || crit_val2.present?
  return false unless crit_val1.present? && crit_val2.present?
end
```

Output:
absent
answer is false

please explain

Comment: I can't find where `crit_val2` comes from. Your code seems to be missing something

Comment: @rodrigoalvesvieira updated

Comment: @anothermh I have simplified the problem. This is a production running code for a feature.

Comment: This should be tagged with [ruby-on-rails] as you are using [`present?`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F).

Comment: `return true unless crit_val1.present? || crit_val2.present?` is the same as `return true if !(crit_val1.present? || crit_val2.present?}`, which is the same as `return true if !crit_val1.present? && !crit_val2.present?`. Does that help?

Comment: Is this supposed to be true if *either* of them is present, or if *both* are? You have two `return` statements, only one of which should be necessary (and implied) and a third possibility where you return `nil` by accident.

Comment: Methods returning `true` or `false` can usually be reduced to a single boolean expression. Something like `crit_val1.present? && crit_val2.present?` – that would return `true` is both are present, and `false` otherwise. No need for an explicit `return`, let alone two separate `returns`.

Comment: BTW, what is your method supposed to do / return? It's not clear to me whether _"absent answer is false"_ is correct or not. Under what circumstances does it work / fail? Show some examples, including the arguments you pass and the (possibly wrong) results it returns. Explain why you expected a different output.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `match_criteria` with one parameter that is a non-blank value, the condition

```
crit_val1.present? || crit_val2.present?
```

will be `true`, but since you are negating it the first return statement does not get called.

In that same situation the second conditional evaluates to false, and since you're negating it the second return successfully returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def match_criteria(crit_val1, crit_val2)
  # Check if #1 is present? or blank?
  if crit_val1.present?
    puts "present"
  else
    puts "absent"
  end

  # Return true unless EITHER (||) are present
  # ...or you could think of it like...
  # Return true if BOTH (&&) are blank
  return true unless crit_val1.present? || crit_val2.present?
  # Return false unless BOTH are present
  # ..or...
  # Return false if EITHER is blank
  return false unless crit_val1.present? && crit_val2.present?
end
```

This is actually a Ruby on Rails question. `blank?` and `present?` are instance methods only available in Rails, but not in the standard Ruby library.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with Ruby (or Rails) *per se*. It has to do with misunderstanding the logical operators involved, which of course would be a problem in any language.

Consider this:

```
def test(x, y)
  return true unless x || y
  false unless x && y
end

p test(true, false)  # => false
p test(true, true)   # => nil
p test(false, false) # => true
```

In the first test (`x = true, y = false`) the first condition fails because `x || y` is true (it would succeed only if `x || y` evaluated to `false`, since you're using `unless` instead of `if`). The second condition succeeds because `x && y` is not true. So, the method returns `false`.

In the second test, neither condition succeeds, because both `x || y` and `x && y` evaluate to `true`. (Again, since you are using `unless` instead of `if`, a condition can only succeed if it evaluates to `false`.) So, the method returns `nil`.

In the third test, the first condition succeeds, because `x || y` evaluates to `false`. So, the method returns `false`.

It's most unlikely that you want these logical conditions. In the first place, you probably don't want a set of logical conditions that doesn't cover all the possibilities. Also, I don't see a reason for using `unless` instead of `if`; it seems like you're needlessly complicating your logic.

Of course, you haven't explained exactly what logical conditions you're looking for, so we're all playing "blind mechanic" here to some extent. But my feeling is that you are attempting to check whether your `crit_val1` or `crit_val2` are present, and return `false` if either of them is. If so, all you would have to do is this:

```
def match_criteria(crit_val1, crit_val2)

    # other stuff

    return false if crit_val1.present? || crit_val2.present?
    true
end
```